Migrate from perforce to git .error for branches
I am having trouble in migrating from perforce to bitbucket.In perforce I have depot called as "DepotWork" inside that I have different streams named as master,v1,v2 etc. All these v1 v2 are taken from master at specific changelist over the decade. Now since I am able to migrate master to git I am not sure how I will migrate the branches with the history.
I tried to create a tag in git repo and created a branch at the changelist where the version is created from main. But it is not able to synchronise the changes
